# ReactJS - ref undefined

Tags: reactjs

I moved away from Alt to Redux and decided to take advantage of context type.
Somewhere in the mix, my ref is now undefined.

**What would be the proper procedure for refs to be available with this code:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
// components
import TopNavMenuItem from './top-nav-menu-item';

export default class TopNavZone extends Component {

   fetchMenu() {
     const results = [];
     const navItems = this.context.navItems;
     navItems.map((item, index) => {
       results.push(
         <TopNavMenuItem key={ index }
           clientId={ this.context.clientInfo._id }
           item={ item }
           index={ index }
           parent={ this.refs.topNavList }
         />
      );
     });
     return results;
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <nav className="top-nav" id="TopNavZone">
          <ul ref="topNavList" className="">
            { this.fetchMenu() }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

TopNavZone.contextTypes = {
  navItems: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  clientInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I captured the ref in ComponentDidMount and made the data part of state instead of calling the function this.fetchMenu from render:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
// components
import TopNavMenuItem from './top-nav-menu-item';

export default class TopNavZone extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); {
      this.state = {
        results: null
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var topNavList = this.refs.topNavList;
    this.setState({ results: this.fetchMenu(topNavList) })
  }

  fetchMenu(topNavList) {
    const results = [];
    const items = this.context.navItems;
    items.map((item, index) => {
      results.push(
        <TopNavMenuItem key={ index }
                        clientId={ this.context.clientInfo._id }
                        item={ item }
                        index={ index }
                        parent={ topNavList }
        />
      );
    });
    return results;
  }
```

---

```
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <nav className="top-nav" id="TopNavZone">
          <ul ref="topNavList" className="">
            { this.state.results }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
TopNavZone.contextTypes = {
  navItems: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  clientInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```